# How to update two database tables after button clicked

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to update two tables in a database after a button is clicked.
Already using an update query separated but sometimes the second query will not run and not updating the table.

This is my update queries

```
 $wpdb->replace($table_name_users,$data_array_users);
 $wpdb->update($table_name,$data_array,$data_where);
```

In this case I post just integers like 0,1,2 etc to database tables this queries is related to wordpress update queries.

What is the problem and how can I fix it out ?

Comment: Please provide more debugging information. What exactly are the values of the fields your are updating?

Comment: @Campbell Just integer like 0,1,2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should add `$format` and `$where_format` as explained in wordpress developers documentation about `wpdb::update` for each array in update query.

Example :

```
wpdb::update( ‘table’, array( ‘column’ => ‘foo’, ‘field’ => ‘bar’ ), array( ‘ID’ => 1 ) ) wpdb::update( ‘table’, array( ‘column’ => ‘foo’, ‘field’ => 1337 ), array( ‘ID’ => 1 ), array( ‘%s’, ‘%d’ ), array( ‘%d’ ) )
```

You can find more information here :

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/